# Equivalent of "android.library=true" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and IntelliJ Idea, as a previous Eclipse user.

The module I'd like to add as a dependency to another module doesn't show up in the list of dependencies available to add to the project.

In Eclipse, inserting android.library=true in project.properties will enable it to be added as a dependency.  How does one make it show up in the available dependency module list in Android Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build.gradle file:

Change apply plugin: 'android' to apply plugin: 'android-library'

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-projects

Answer (score 2):

The @An answer is correct.

However this syntax is old. You should use this inside your `build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Also you should check if in `settings.gradle` there is the library module.

```
include ':app' , ':library' //,':library2'.....
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, although @An was first and he will get the check.  Thanks tho!